# Spring Json date and time formatting

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, datetime-format

I'm looking for some help in formatting a date and time stamp in Spring.

My property is annotated like this:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yy hh:mm")
@Column(name = "start_time")
private Date startTime;
```

and then passed into my instance in my data loader like

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy hh:mm");
    String startTimeSt = "05-11-2018 12:00";
    Date startTime = null;
    try {
        startTime = dateFormat.parse(startTimeSt);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Booking booking1 = new Booking(customer1, gemma, startTime);
    bookingRepository.save(booking1);
```

But it is returned in my json file like

```
"startTime": "2018-11-05T00:00:00.000+0000",
```

How do I get the time to show?

I have also tried passing `spring.gson.date-format=dd-MM-yy hh:mm` into my application.properties file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hours in a date format is specified as HH (uppercase) not hh as in your code example - please try using HH in your format and setting the shape property of the `@JsonFormat` annotation as follows:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yy HH:mm")
```

See the following tutorial on `@JsonFormat`:

https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-jsonformat